# Rest the values of 2 objects in NodeJS / Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 objects:

```
const  totalConso =  [ 
      { horoseason: 'BASE', value: 0 },          
      { horoseason: 'HPH', value: 0 },
      { horoseason: 'HCH', value: 0 },
      { horoseason: 'HPE', value: 5853.16 },
      { horoseason: 'HCE', value: 4460.99 } 
    ] 

 const  totalAutoConso =   [ { horoseason: 'HPH', value: 0 },
      { horoseason: 'HCH', value: 0 },
      { horoseason: 'HPE', value: 2354.62 },
      { horoseason: 'HCE', value: 0 } 
    ]
```

I would like rest their value.

I can do it like that, but it doesn't seem very elegant

```
   onst totalConsoBase = totalConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "BASE").shift()
const totalAutoConsoBase = totalAutoConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "BASE").shift()

const totalConsoHPH = totalConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "HPH").shift()
const totalAutoConsoHPH = totalAutoConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "HPH").shift()

const totalConsoHCH = totalConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "HCH").shift()
const totalAutoConsoHCH = totalAutoConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "HCH").shift()

const totalConsoHPE = totalConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "HPE").shift()
const totalAutoConsoHPE = totalAutoConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "HPE").shift()

const totalConsoHCE = totalConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "HCE").shift()
const totalAutoConsoHCE = totalAutoConso.filter(it => it.horoseason === "HCE").shift()
console.log(totalConsoBase, totalAutoConsoBase, totalConsoHPH, totalAutoConsoHPH)

const totalGridConso = [
    {
        horoseason: "BASE",
        value: typeof totalConsoBase !== 'undefined' ? totalConsoBase.value - totalAutoConsoBase.value : null
    }, {
        horoseason: "HPH",
        value: typeof totalConsoHPH !== 'undefined' ? totalConsoHPH.value - totalAutoConsoHPH.value : null
    }, {
        horoseason: "HCH",
        value: typeof totalConsoHCH !== 'undefined' ? totalConsoHCH.value - totalAutoConsoHCH.value : null
    }, {
        horoseason: "HPE",
        value: typeof totalConsoHPE !== 'undefined' ? totalConsoHPE.value - totalAutoConsoHPE.value : null
    }, {
        horoseason: "HCE",
        value: typeof totalConsoHCE !== 'undefined' ? totalConsoHCE.value - totalAutoConsoHCE.value : null
    },
]
```

Is there any way I can improve my code ?

Comment: Quick question: is your current `totalGridConso` giving the answer you expect? From my initial run, and logically, it's not subtracting values correctly. I have come up with a possible answer but the output from my solution is different than the output from your `totalGridConso`

Comment: yes, I have a mistake ! I should shift().value . But shift returns an empty array, I am in trouble

Comment: No worries, I'll post my answer with a few assumptions for now. Let me know if it works for you, if not I'll try editing my answer with your requirements. :)

Comment: I edit my question with an extra : BASE horoseason to make appear this case

Comment: now updated with working code. Sorry for that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the JavaScript [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function for arrays.

For your updated example, I would come up with something as follows:

```
const totalGridConso = totalConso.map(x => {
  const totalAutoConsoValue = totalAutoConso.filter(y => y.horoseason == x.horoseason).shift()
  return {
    horoseason: x.horoseason,
    value: typeof totalAutoConsoValue != 'undefined' ? x.value - totalAutoConsoValue.value : null
  }
})
```

This solution is assuming that your `totalAutoConso` does not have two objects with the same `horoseason` type.

P.S. I have updated my initial answer when you updated your question.

Comment: I think you'll find that `array.find(...)` is more conventional than `array.filter(...).shift()`

Comment: I definitely agree. I wasn't sure from the OP's initial question hence the mention of my assumption regarding two objects with the same `horoseason`.

Comment: It wouldn't matter whether you made that assumption or not, they're functionally equivalent to each other since the callback is pure.

Comment: Thanks, working like a charm ! @PatrickRoberts also a big thanks for array.find() !